# This site isn't a tutoring service... but I know of one

Tags: discussion

And I have tutored on it before. And if everyone who needed Python tutoring services hired me via that service rather than asking an off-topic question on SO, SO would be much tidier and I would stand to benefit financially.

Is there some way we could route some of SO's off-topic content to a place where it would be more appropriate? I didn't want to just start leaving comments on such questions along the lines of "guiding you through all the issues in your code and teaching you several concepts along the way isn't appropriate here, but you can hire me on XYZ site and I'll be happy to help." It has connotations of SO being the free tier of a paid service (even when the other site has no connection to SO), there'd be room for abuse with false claims of off-topic questions, and it reminds me of that Other Site where users pay for answers.

For those reasons, I've been leery of bringing this up. But, I mean... could it possibly work? To any degree? Am I even allowed to tell askers of off-topic "my professor hasn't responded so I need someone else to read me my textbook" questions the name of the tutoring site I use? Maybe a link to my profile there? I really don't know.

It would be so nice if I could spend my time here answering good questions and my time on the tutoring site making money, rather than spending my time here wading through low-quality questions and my time on the tutoring site... well, not spending time on the tutoring site, because it seems like there aren't many people willing to pay for the right thing when there's a chance that a quick off-topic question on SO can get them what they want at no cost.

**What may and may not be done to direct off-topic content to a more appropriate venue, where I would stand to profit?**

Comment: I doubt SO will just funnel you users for the benefit of you getting revenue from them.

Comment: @bjb568 - I clearly stated that SO would benefit from the reduction in off-topic questions. That kind of question only benefits rep whores.

Comment: You could say something like "you might want to look into a tutoring service", but telling people to pay you for an answer is frowned upon.

Comment: @TinyGiant - I do that, but then someone dumps out a "try this" code, and the asker shares the success story with their friends, and they all ask similar questions, and they get answers, ad infinitum, and I end up having to tell people to look into a tutoring service a _lot_... I don't think it actually helps much. I just want to know if "you need a tutor" is the limit, or if there are any other useful things we might be able to do/say.

Comment: Dont worry about the people asking the questions. If it helps you, imagine that the question was generated by a machine. If the question is off-topic and the community cannot edit it to be on-topic without changing it completely, vote to close it. If you can edit a question to turn it into a good on-topic question without changing it completely, do so. Once you have done everything that you can, assess the question and vote up or down based on how useful you percieve the question to be. No good can from investing energy into individuals at this scale. Invest your energy in the content instead.

Comment: @PaulCrovella - I thought that maybe if there were a more accepted/sanctioned way to handle such questions, it might eventually supplant such answers.

Comment: I don't know why this is being read as "give me all your money" when I explicitly said that I wanted to avoid that. The financial benefit to me is the whole reason I've been avoiding it. I was just hoping for a better way to put content where it belongs. I mean, if a question is opinion-based, I recommend Quora or Reddit or something. I've never once mentioned the tutoring service I occasionally use, for this exact reason.

Comment: The main issue I have with this, and where you are conpletely losing me,is "hire me instead". Might be good for SO, but it still looks like you just want to make a buck (I don't think that's your intent, but it sure looks like it)

Comment: @Patrice - You don't think it looks like I have any interest in cutting down on the lazy "my homework is due tomorrow" questions? Look how often I mention the need for askers to seek out a tutorial [in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2617068/tigerhawkt3?tab=activity&sort=comments). Would you have the same reaction to a shoe salesman wishing that people would stop interrupting his Sunday dinner to ask for his advice on shoes?

Comment: @Tigerhawk well here people aren't asking YOU a question, so yes this is very different. They are coming to a community and asking something. Again, I get your end goal and it is laudable. Just addressing the "hire me" part, which is what seems to rub people off the wrong way.

Comment: @Patrice - I guess it's more like several hundred people wandering into a restaurant and asking if any shoe experts can give them some free advice. Yes, askers are asking ME a question, along with every other potential answerer. It's a huge contribution to noise on the site. Hiring a tutor is the right solution for some of the questions around here; why shouldn't we be able to be any more specific than that? "I don't want other people to make money" isn't an answer to that. I'd like to see some actual reasoning here.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: "*I don't know why this is being read as "give me all your money"*" Because you said: "*I would stand to benefit financially.*" and "*where I would stand to profit*" That's basically you admitting that you're suggesting this for your own benefit more than for ours.

Comment: @NicolBolas - No, that was me being up-front rather than telling a lie of omission.

Answer (score 17):

OK, let's ignore the explicit statements in your post where you are clearly trying to use SO to steer revenue into your pocket. Let's take it purely on face value: should SO have what is effectively a close option that says, "go to a tutoring site?"

No. Because it won't accomplish anything.

Right now, it takes 5 votes to close a question. And in many cases, that's still long enough of a period of time to attract answers of dubious quality and applicability. The only exception is duplicates, which permits tag gold badge holders to unilaterally close them with an appropriate link. And even then, that's sometimes not fast enough.

Adding a new close reason will change nothing about this. Such questions can still get answers in before they get closed. And if SO isn't willing to allow a single person to unilaterally close a question for not having an MCVE, they're *certainly* not going to allow them to do so for your tutoring site.

So what exactly will this change about SO? People generally don't read close reasons as it is. Just look at how many people can't follow the link to MCVE or How to Ask and so forth. So it seems to me that all this (presumably free) advertising will do is... advertise.

Furthermore, "hire a tutor" may be an answer, but it's certainly not the *only* such off-site answer. "Read <insert book here>" might also work. So might "Read <insert tutorial here>". Or "Go to your teacher/TA." Maybe some people have on-campus tutoring that doesn't cost money; why can't we funnel people to that? Or any number of other resources.

Why should we prefer "hire a tutor" over those other alternatives? Particularly when "hire a tutor" costs money and the others may not.

Also, if SO is going to get into funneling people to off-site resources, why not make them *pay* for the privilege? If Amazon books could be an answer, why shouldn't Stack Exchange make Amazon pay an advertising fee for sending people there? If you want your tutoring site to be linked as well, why should SE do that for free? Generally speaking, advertising costs money.

And there's no reason for SE to do you a personal favor.

Answer (score 11):

I agree many askers on SO would benefit from talking to a tutor.

I also don't think having community users "profit" from a situation like that is *necessarily* and *inherently* immoral; a lot of people "profit" from Stack Overflow - owners, shareholders, employees.

There is, however, a strong consensus that any kind of money-for-help scheme would harm the community, which currently runs (and runs fairly well) on love and reputation points.

Also, any practical implementation of something like this would be a living hell.

To start with, most lazy askers are unlikely to be willing or able to shell out money for a paid tutor in the first place. And even when they are: you would have to set up a system that refers people to a load of people the system doesn't know. Vetting those people in every tag single tag would be a nightmare. SO would likely have to take a cut for this to make any sense to them; the logistics of that would be *another* nightmare. When fees are paid somehow through SO, people would (somewhat rightly) assume the people referred are endorsed by the company. Etc. etc.

So, best leave this be.